# Mock a private method of the class under test in JMockit

Tags: java, junit, mocking, jmockit

In my class under test (CUT) - an ejb - I have a private method "getConnection".
I want to test another method of the CUT but this method will fail before hand.

I tried it like shown below, but "invoke" is wrong. I don't want to invoke the method, I want to stub it. But how? ('connection' is a stub)

```
new NonStrictExpectations() {
  {
    invoke(archivingBean, "getConnection");result = connection;
  }
};
archivingBean.moveCreditBasic2Archive(new Date());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test is correct, except that it's missing a declaration for the *mocked type*. The EJB class, in this case.

Normally, mocked types are mocked in full (all methods). In such cases, you would declare a `@Mocked MyEJB archivingBean` parameter to the test method, for example.

For *partial* mocking, on the other hand, you use the `NonStrictExpectations(Object...)` constructor, like this:

```
new NonStrictExpectations(archivingBean) {{ // <== note the argument here
    invoke(archivingBean, "getConnection"); result = connection;
}};
```

Comment: Seems the latest version of jmockit doesn't have a  "invoke " method

Comment: Those methods are static imports from the `mockit.Deencapsulation` class.