# Mock private methods of the class under test in jmockit

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, jmockit

I want to test process method of the `ProcessServiceImpl` class, with mocking private methods: `readContent` and `isValidFile` and `userService` class.

```
@Named("processServiceImpl")
public class ProcessServiceImpl {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    public User process(Long userId, File inputFile) throws InvalidFileException {
        User user = userService.load(userId);
        String fileContent = readContent(inputFile);
        if (isValidFile(fileContent)) {
            User updatedUser = userService.updateUser(user, fileContent);
            return updatedUser;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidFileException();
        }
    }

    private String readContent(File inputFile) {
        //implementation
    }

    private boolean isValidFile(String fileContent) {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

I mocked up `UserService` and injected it successfully. but i can't mock the private methods of the class under the test. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427685/mocking-private-method-of-class-under-test-using-jmockit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218726/mock-a-private-method-of-the-class-under-test-in-jmockit) links i tried to mock them with `NonStrictExpectations` but it has not any `invoke` method!! Is there another way to do this? (I'm using jmockit-1.8)

```
new NonStrictExpectations(processServiceImpl) {{
    invoke(processServiceImpl, "readContent"); 
    result = "";
}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `invoke(...)` methods are from the `mockit.Deencapsulation` class.

But I would recommend to *not* mock the `private` methods. Instead, use a real file with valid contents for your tests.

Comment: You are right in this specific use case. But in a complex private method that depends on some classes (method calls), i think it's not so bad to mock it instead of mocking all of dependent classes.

Comment: @Rogério what is possible way in 1.48 jmockit?